# Add computed field to linq projection with automapper

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, automapper

Having a mapping with automapper that maps Orders entity to OrdersDto
i would add a computed field not in domain table (Orders)

I do not kwnow if is possible and if i asked correctly but i hope code will be helpful

```
CreateMap<Orders, OrdersDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, conf => conf.MapFrom(i => i.OrderId))
            ...other fields

var orders = _ordersRepository.GetOrders();//<==Orders Table
var ordersView = (from o in orders
                  join s in solvency on o.Code equals s.Code 
                              into os
                              from x in os.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              let computed = ...
                              select new
                              {
                                  fields...
                                  MyComputed = x.computed //<== want to include
                              })
                            .ToList();
```

I would my query in action controller to be more readable using

```
ProjectTo<OrdersDto>()
```

removing projection to anonimous object with linq

Comment: You do that with MapFrom.

Comment: Ok but how ? This is the question. I use automapper just a little bit. Im not expert

Comment: You already did that for the Id property.

Comment: Yes but Id exists in table. MyComputed is a sql case calculated on query... how do that?